# Cannot get CollectionViewCells to work in SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have tried this numerous ways but I am unable to get it to work. I am trying to add a simple image and two text labels to a collection view cell and when the build completes the tableview is just blank. I am brand new too SWIFT but I am pretty sure I am missing something simple. What am I doing wrong?

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    let locationName = ["Hawaii Resort", "Mountain Expedition", "Scuba Diving"]
    let locationImage = [UIImage(named: "img0"), UIImage(named: "img1"), UIImage(named: "img2")]
    let locationDescription = ["Lorem Ipsum 0", "Lorem Ipsum 1", "Lorem Ipsum 2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locationName.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.locationName.text = locationName[indexPath.row]
        cell.locationImage.image = locationImage[indexPath.row]
        cell.locationDescription.text = locationDescription[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

**CollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationDescription: UILabel!
}
```

[image]

Comment: your collectionView delegate and dataSource are set i assumed

Comment: I have updated the attached image and used the solution suggested below but it did not work. Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the collectionView to the ViewController.
Beneath locationDescription add:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Then connect it on the storyboard.
Then within the viewDidLoad,set the delegate and data source to self

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.datasource = self
```

Comment: are you sure he forget to add these lines ? i think he set them in storyboard

Comment: I added both of the self.collectionView lines that were recommended  and I get an error message for both lines that says, "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I also updated the image to include how they are connected to the storyboard.

Comment: If you added the above code in viewDidLoad, you can remove the storyboard delegate/datasource. Instead you need to create an IBoutlet of the collectionView (as I mentioned above) and connect that. The current “expression is ambiguous” is probably bc it can’t tell which collectionView you are trying to reference.